# Visibility binding on TextView not working

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I am having problems binding `Visibility` to `TextView`. I have verified that the bound property returns a bool false. I also have a `Checkbox` whose `Visibility` is bound to the same property and that seems to work. See below:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    local:MvxBind="Checked ConfirmLock; Visibility Visibility(ConfirmLockVisible)"
    style="@style/checkbox" />

<TextView
    android:text="Confirm Lock"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    localMvxBind="Visibility Visibility(ConfirmLockVisible)"
    style="@style/form_label.spacer" />
```

In the `ViewModel`:

```
private bool _confirmLockVisible;
public bool ConfirmLockVisible
{
    get { return _confirmLockVisible; }
    set
    {
        _confirmLockVisible = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ConfirmLockVisible);
    }
}
```

There is nothing special happening in the `ViewModel`, just that the property is being set based on data returned from a database query. And based on the behavior of the `Checkbox`, it appears that the property is set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `:` in your `TextView` binding there:

`localMvxBind="Visibility Visibility(ConfirmLockVisible)"`

should be

`local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(ConfirmLockVisible)"`